Need to replace a string in directory recursively using ansible playbook
I have used replace model in ansible play book to replace string from "/var/app/test/abc/80526" to "/var/app/test/abc/80528" in directory, searching inside the directory /var/app/test
Directory name:- /var/app/test
In above directory we have multiple folders which contain different file need to search for all the files and replace "/var/app/test/abc/80526" to "/var/app/test/abc/80528" in all the files.
Error which I am facing: - When I have tried the below code getting error as /var/app/test is a directory.
below values we are passing through parm `your text`
/var/app=inst_path
test=inst_name
oldver=80526
new_version=80528

     - name: Replace the 80526 configuration path with 80528 Configuration path
       ansible.builtin.replace:
         path: "{{ inst_path }}/{{ inst_name }}"
         regexp: "{{ inst_path }}/{{ inst_name }}/abc/{{ old_version }}"
         replace: "{{ inst_path }}/{{ inst_name }}/abc/{{ new_version }}"
    
    
    
    
          getting error as /var/app/test is directory. 

need to replace /var/app/test/abc/80526 to /var/app/test/abc/80528 in all the files inside directory


Are you trying to move files from one directory to another, or does the string /var/app/test/abc/80526 exist INSIDE the files in /var/app/test?

inst_name is not defined anywhere so your path resolves to /var/app/ which is obviously a directory as the error message points out. Your post is hard to read because you did not take time to format it correctly. Please read formatting. Moreover it is merely impossible to reproduce your problem leaving the floor to wild guesses from other users as this is not a [mre]. As you're new here, you might also want to read [ask]. Good luck.

Hi Sam,
yes string "/var/app/test/abc/80526" exist INSIDE the files in /var/app/test directory.
need to replace the string "/var/app/test/abc/80526" with "/var/app/test/abc/80528" in all the files in directory /var/app/test.

The replace module works on a single file. The error is that you are targeting a directory, wanting to replace a string in many files. You'll need to combine the find module with a loop in your replace module.
For readability, I'm going to hard code values, but you can switch back to your string interpolation.
- name: Get list of files
  ansible.builtin.find:
    paths: /var/app/test
    recurse: true
  register: found_files

- name: Replace text in those files
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: '{{ item.path }}'
    regexp: /var/app/test/abc/80526
    replace: /var/app/test/abc/80528
  loop: '{{ found_files.files }}'
    

The find module returns a dictionary that responds to .files which returns a list of dictionaries for each file. Each of those dictionaries responds to .path to return the full path to the file. You can see all of this by using the debug module.
